# Difference between Azure static website and blob container integration with CDN

Tags: azure

There are two ways of making a blob container accessible via CDN.

The first way is to point the CDN directly to the blob container, documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn

```
Origin type: Storage 
Origin hostname: NAME.blob.core.windows.net.  
Origin host header: NAME.blob.core.windows.net.  
Origin path: /www (container name)
```

The second way is to map the $web blob container "static website" url to your CDN, documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/storage/blobs/static-website-content-delivery-network

In this scenario you need to enable the "static website" option on your storage account.
Example configuration of a CDN endpoint:

```
Origin type: Custom Origin
Origin hostname: NAME.z6.web.core.windows.net (static website public url)
Origin host header: NAME.z6.blob.core.windows.net (static website public url)
Origin path: (empty)
```

Both methods map a blob container to the CDN endpoint. But the 2nd option has an additional, possibly unneeded, static website endpoint.

Can somebody explain the use-cases? It seems like the static website method is less flexible as you need to use the $web container specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like the static website method is less flexible as you need
> to use the $web container specifically.

There are two distinct advantages you get out of hosting static website in Azure Storage:

1. **Support for default document**: In this case you can directly use `NAME.z6.web.core.windows.net` to serve the default document otherwise you will have to specify the full path like `NAME.blob.core.windows.net/container/index.html`, and
2. **Custom error page for 404 error**: You can have a custom 404 error page when hosting your static website in `$web` container otherwise you get standard 404 error message if a blob is not available in the blob container.

These things are not available when you host a static website in any other blob container.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. In regards to privacy -- if I were to want my private container to only be accessible through CDN with a custom endpoint appended with a SAS token, for example -- I presume the blob storage method would be more suitable here? From my testing it looks like the $web container is available publicly regardless of it's container privacy settings.

Comment: You can change the ACL of $web container to private. If you access it via `NAME.z6.web.core.windows.net` then it would have no impact however if you will need a Shared Access Signature when you access it via `NAME.blob.core.windows.net/$web/index.html`.